# How can I write an array to another .js file?

Tags: javascript, api

So I'm making a webApp that involves thousands of API queries. Since the API has a limit on the amount of queries I can send it per day, I was wondering if I could simply run the query loop a single time and then write the resulting objects to an array in a new file.

is this possible?

Comment: Your question is so vague I don't even know what to suggest to help. Try a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You want to make calls, then create cache, then use cache instead of call.

Are you on client side or in server side js ?

Client side will be tricky, but server side is easy :

Files can be a cache, so does a DB or a lot of tools (memcached, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just send the array to JSON.stringify() and write it to a file.

If you are using Node.js it would look something like this:

```
function writeResponse(resp, cb)
{
  fs.writeFile('response.json', JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2), function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if(cb) cb();
  });
}
```

If you are in a browser you can use the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) which allows storage in key/value pairs up to 10Mb. If that doesn't work, maybe write a quick Node.js server that works as a caching proxy. A quick google search suggests that you might be able to find one ready to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use local storage, which is accessible across your domain, and will remain on the users computer indefinitely. Perhaps something like this:

```
function getData(){
    var data = localStorage.getItem("myData");
    if(data === null){
         data = makeQuery();
         localStorage.setItem("myData", data);
    }
    return data
}
```